# When watching a movie (Dune 2) in an IMAX recently I noticed a static texture that remained as the image panned - what is that?

Tags: imax, projection, display-technology

When watching Dune 2 recently (in the Odeon Greenwich, UK on the IMAX screen) there were several occasions where the image panned but there was some kind of screen/projector texture that became visible because it wasn't moving whilst its background (the movie) was. The texture did not cover the whole image, just the top right quadrant roughly.

I can't find any description of this (maybe I'm using the wrong terminology) so I'm not sure if it was "normal" (but I hope not as it was a bit disruptive!) or a flaw with the projection system/screen at that theatre or even a flaw with the movie itself (which seems unlikely as I can't find any similar descriptions).

I have seen a few other questions/answers about a stuttering effect (with IMAX) which can be related to different frame rates between the film and the projector but that doesn't sound the same as this.

I guess another way to visualise it would be that if you were projecting onto a white brick wall you would be able to ignore the brick pattern whilst the image was basically stationary but if it panned then the brick pattern would suddenly stand out. The effect was not *that* bad but was still noticeable...

Comment: was it like looking through a screen door? https://johncanfield.me/blog/disappointing-world-imax-liemax/ - “IMAX - real IMAX - presents reality. Not reality as seen through a screen door.”

Comment: https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g186338-d7116392-Reviews-Odeon_Cinema_Greenwich-London_England.html#REVIEWS "Mar 2024 - The movie Dune Part 2 was spoiled by a very dirty screen. You could clearly see blotches and dirt if the movie scene was light or bright. Very poor maintenance"

Comment: The reviews for the place seem horrendous.

Comment: Blobby, you should probably post that stuff fleshed out as an answer as this is a rather specific question.

Comment: Was the silver screen textured, perhaps? Badly maintained, especially in the upper right corner?

Comment: I wonder if whatever it was would have been visible after the house lights were up?

Comment: _"which can be related to different frame rates between the film and the projector but that doesn't sound the same as this."_ I'm pretty sure Odean is not showing Dune 2 in IMAX 70mm, only in digital IMAX and regular 70mm. Any idea which type of showing you were in?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the current comments and the reviews that @blobbymcblobby found I think the most likely explanation is that the screen was dirty and poorly maintained, so genuinely did have a texture on it.

The issue doesn't match any of the other more technical IMAX issues that I've found information on such as the "frame rate stutter" or the "screen door" effect that BMcB mentions.

I guess I should have checked the reviews of the location first!